# Proving that a function is bijective + finding its inverse function

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the following function is bijective and find its inverse function.

Let X be a set and A a subset of X.

f : P(X) → P(X)

A →  the complement of set A

It's the first time I'm asked to do this with power sets and sets, so I have no idea of what I'm supposed to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to show that $f$ is injective and surjective. (Hint: what is $f\circ f$? )

Comment: Isn't the complement of the complement of a set the initial set itself? Thus, $f$ must be its own inverse...

Comment: I guess $f\circ f$ = A but what does that prove?

Answer (score 0):

If the function has two sided inverse then the function is bijective.
Here $(f\circ f)(A)=f(f(A))=f(A^c)=(A^c)^c=A=i(A).$ Where $i$ is the identity function.

Inverse of $f$ is itself $f$.

Comment: So is the inverse function $A^c\to A$ or $A\to A$ ?

Comment: Or is it $A\to A^c$?